# Backbone.js + Rest. Collection is not populated after fetch()

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I'm new in Backbone. So I'm trying to fetch data from REST service.

this is my simple code:

```
$(function () {

    var Entity = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function() {
            return 'http://localhost:8080/rest/entity/'+this.id;
        }
    });

    var EntityList = Backbone.Collection.extend({       
        model: Entity,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/entity'
    });

    var entityList = new EntityList();

    entityList.fetch();

});
```

my rest service returns next JSON:

```
[{"id":1387,
  "version":3,
  "entityName":"entity01",
  "entityLabel":"Entity01",
  "entityPluralLabel":"Entity01",
  "attributes":
     [{"id":1425,
       "slot":"D001",
       "version":0,
       "attributeName":"dfield",
       "attributeType":
          {"id":7,
           "description":"Date",
           "attributeType":"date",
           "databaseType":"DATE"
          },
       "options":[],
       "order":2,
       "attributeLabel":"dField",
       "checked":null
      },
      {"id":1424,
       "slot":"S001",
       "version":0,
       "attributeName":"txfield",
       "attributeType":
          {"id":1,
           "description":"Textbox",
           "attributeType":"textbox",
           "databaseType":"STRING"
          },
       "options":[],
       "order":1,
       "attributeLabel":"txField",
       "checked":null
      }
     ]  
 },
 {"id":1426,
  "version":3,
  "entityName":"entity02",
  "entityLabel":"Entity02",
  "entityPluralLabel":"Entity02",
  "attributes":
     [{"id":1464,
       "slot":"D001",
       "version":0,
       "attributeName":"dfield",
       "attributeType":
          {"id":7,
           "description":"Date",
           "attributeType":"date",
           "databaseType":"DATE"
          },
       "options":[],
       "order":2,
       "attributeLabel":"dField",
       "checked":null
      }
     ]
 }
]
```

In debugger I see that request was sent to REST service and response was recieved, how can I see if entityList collection is populated with recieved data or not? In debugger entityList.models is empty after entityList.fetch();

Am I on right way or somthing is wrong with my code?

Comment: backbone's sourcecode is pretty simple. Maybe it helps just stepping through the actual backbone source to see what's going on.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I think you are on the right way.  But because `Backbone.Collection.fetch()` is async, you should check value of `entityList.models` not right after the method call, but in `success` callback of fetch.

That is, this code will say that models list is empty:

```
entityList.fetch();
console.log(entityList.models); // => 0 (collection being fetched)
```

while this code will print number of models in the collection when it have been populated:

```
entityList.fetch({success: function(){
    console.log(entityList.models); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
}});
```

Comment: additionally, consider overloading the `parse` function on the collection.  It'll let you see the response as it arrives, and I often find that I want to do more than just populate the objects at that time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you're right about async fetch, I found this suddenly during debugging :)

Comment: This saved me hours of troubleshooting.  I was wanting to use the collection right after fetching, but it was empty.  Adding a success handler to fetch allowed the collection to populate correctly. Thanks!