# Backbone collection.fetch(), parse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js and I want to fetch data for my Collection from server:

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend();
var AccountList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Account,

        url: '/pfp/accounts/service',

        parse: function(response){
            return response.Data;
        }

    });
var accountList = new AccountList;
accountList.fetch();
console.log(accountList.toJSON());
```

Server response:

```
{"Data":
[{"accountid":"101752","account_name":"hijklmnopq","userid":"1","comment":"mnopqrstu","creation_date":"6 Jan 2008","account_type":"2","acc_type_name":"Дебетовая карта","currency":"144","letter_code":"","start_balance":"90.000.000","start_balance_raw":90000000.000,"to_total":true},
{"accountid":"144924","account_name":"emabcefghijklmnopqr","userid":"1","comment":"lmno","creation_date":"19 Jan 2008","account_type":"4","acc_type_name":"Банковский счёт","currency":"113","letter_code":"Le","start_balance":"360.000.000,00","start_balance_raw":360000000.000,"to_total":true},
...
```

accountList.toJSON() return empty array ([ ]).
Please help me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: This is a common question -- fetch is asynchronous as [documented](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). You'll need to add a `success` callback in the call to fetch, or connect to one of the reset/add events of the collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259712/backbone-js-rest-collection-is-not-populated-after-fetch

Comment: Also note that is should be `var accountList = new AccountList();`

Answer (score 4):

So, as WiredPrairie said, you need to change those lines:

```
accountList.fetch();
console.log(accountList.toJSON());
```

to:

```
accountList.fetch({
  success: function(collection){
    // This code block will be triggered only after receiving the data.
    console.log(collection.toJSON()); 
  }
});
// JS will likely reach this line before receiving the data.
```