# How do I access a backbone collection's fetched results?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection which I know is fetching the entire collection, but how do I get access to the data returned from the fetch?

**/js/views/idea.js**

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'collections/ideas'
], function($, _, Backbone, IdeasCollection) {

  var IdeasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#container'),
    render: function(){

      this.collection = new IdeasCollection();

      console.log( this.collection.fetch() ); // I can see data

      var data = {};
      var template = _.template( $('#ideasView').html(), data);

      $('body').removeClass().addClass('blog');
      this.$el.html( template );
    }
  });

  return IdeasView;
});
```

**/js/collections/ideas.js** (Shortened for brevity.)

```
  var IdeasCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/ideas',
    model: IdeaModel
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is asynchronous. You must use the event binding style.

```
var IdeasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
      this.collection = new IdeasCollection();
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
      this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function(){
      var template = _.template( $('#ideasView').html(), this.collection.toArray());

      $('body').removeClass().addClass('blog');
      this.$el.html( template );
    }
  });

  return IdeasView;
});
```

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15385066/361833, I can add a callback to fetch. Wouldn't that be cleaner rather than attaching an event handler? Just curious.

Comment: You can do either events or success handler callbacks. Events are more properly idiomatic to backbone, and sometimes can be more correct (respond no matter how many times the event fires), but either works. The main point is you understand that it's not synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
var that = this;

this.collection = new IdeasCollection();
this.collection.fetch({success: function (){
    that.render();
}});
```