# backbone.js won't fetch data and populate the collection

Tags: rest, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I have this setup: require.js + backbone.js, that which populate the collection using fetch function of backbone

**orders.js(collection)**

```
define([
  'underscore', 
  'backbone', 
  'models/item'
  ], function(_, Backbone, Item){

    var Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Item,
        url: 'json/items',

        initialize: function(){
        },

  });

  return orders = new Orders();

});
```

**orders.js(views)**

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'collections/orders',
  'models/item',
  'text!templates/orders.tpl',
  ], function($, _, Backbone, Orders, Item, ordersTemplate){
  var OrdersView = Backbone.View.extend({

    model: Orders,
    template: _.template(ordersTemplate),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);    

        Orders.fetch({ success: function() {
            console.log(Orders.models)
        }});
    },

  });



  return OrdersView;
});
```

Orders.fetch won't populate the collection, though browser detects XHR json/items:

I already tried this solution [Backbone.js + Rest. Collection is not populated after fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259712/backbone-js-rest-collection-is-not-populated-after-fetch) but still it won't work. Is there any way it can fetch data and populate it automatically to the collection? Or am I missing something?

PS: sorry for the brute code posting...

EDIT: success callback on fetch won't do anything but json/items just called by XHR on browser

EDIT: update code on order.js, removed the STORE param

EDIT: i appreciate if you can look on to this url http://mindanaojobs.net/backbone/ and inspect something in it, jsfiddle seems a little bit tricky

Comment: Just did a fiddle and refreshed your URL to see that you fixed it. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Does the XHR response contain an array of objects? If there is any kind of object wrapper like

```
{items: [{...}, {...}]}
```

then you need to implement the `parse` method accordingly.

Yes, I looked at your code and you need this in your Orders collection:

```
parse: function (response) { return response.items;}
```

Comment: I am using that JSON format but still it won't populate, another thing i forgot to mention is that success callback on fetch won't do anything but instead it just load the XHR

Comment: You need to implement `parse` like I said. Backbone expects a PLAIN RAW ARRAY of objects. You are sending back a wrapper. See my edited answer.

Comment: @user1076813 checked your link, Backbone expects JSON array of items while you return object `{items:[]}`. Either you add `parse` method in orders collection as @PeterLyons suggests, or return plain array `[]` from your backend.

Comment: working now on the parse method, but the problem now is it returns an error: undefined is not a function Backbone.js(1.0.0):906, is it that the json isn't matched to the models? sorry i couldn't grasp the hang of it, still new in this stack, i updated the code, i appreciate if you can look at this? http://mindanaojobs.net/backbone/

Comment: and i think there is something wrong with the collection.reset(data)? w/c is kinda incompatible to add data to the collection?

Comment: Your initial question has been answered correctly. Go slower and read the tutorials. You are totally capable of getting this to work, and you are now straying far from the question and answer format of stackoverflow.

Comment: oh, yeah, thanks for it, i just missed something that i forgot to mention in this thread, the fetch and parse is okay, the problem is in the encoding of the json file that i have to validate it through lint