# How do I run a basic GET / synch request in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

I'm no sure I'm using the correct words, but I've looked at the localTodos app, and a few other online tutorials.

I'm reading in to Addy's free online book here:

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#implementation-specifics

but right now I'm getting too much theory and just need to do a basic GET from my server and populate my Collection.

Can someone provide a hello World for a GET / synch request.  All the mysql tables are set up and so is the code that provides a nice JSON stream of my table, neatly organized.

I shouldn't need to install a PHP framework as I can respond with the JSON stream just fine on my own.

I just need a starting point as I'm guessing it will be a few weeks before the book hits this if it does at all.

I tagged this PHP but I don't think it should matter, as all Backbone will see is a JSON stream.

Comment: all that sais is to set the url property and run a fetch().  I'm looking for a practical and general hello world example.  The question is to specific and toward a particular project.

Comment: the answer doesn't provide much working info as the snippets he provides don't even have matching variable names.

Comment: I wrote a [Backbone CRUD](https://github.com/coding-idiot/BackboneCRUD) just to make things clear when I was learning as dealing with server can be a bit tricky in the beginning.

Comment: have you gone through the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch), what part is unclear and what code have you tried ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259712/backbone-js-rest-collection-is-not-populated-after-fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the basics are.

use "fetch" to get something from server.

use "save" to put or post something from server.

use "destroy" to delete something from server.

To perform fetch you'll need a code like this:

Inside your Model

```
//Coffescript
url: "pathToYourAPi/"

getAllFromServer:->
    @fetch()

 //Javascript
 url: "pathToYourAPi/",

 getAllFromServer: function() {
     return this.fetch();
 }
```

This is the simplest way to get data from server. But if you want to get an specific data from server, you maybe should pass an Id or something.

```
//Coffeescript
url:"/pathToYourAPi/"    

setAttributes:->
    @set("id": 1)

getItenFromServer:->
    @fetch()


// Javascript
setAttributes: function() {
    return this.set({"id": 1});
   },
getItenFromServer: function() {
   return this.fetch();
  }
```

It will request to your api path passing the number 1 as "parameter" to server.

If you want to specify the data that you want to sendo to server in another way, you need pass a Object called data when you're "fetching"

example inside model.

```
//Coffescript
GetSomeData: ->
    @fetch({ data:{ id: 1}})

//Javascript
GetSomeData: function() {
return this.fetch({data: {"id": 1}
});
```

I have a post about tips using backbone, unfortunately it's only available in portuguese.
try to use google to translate it.

http://www.rcarvalhojs.com/dicas/de/backbone/2014/06/04/5dicas-backbone.html.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is this language here -> `setAttributes:->
    @set("id": 1)`

Comment: Coffeescipt, but I mistake the set code, the correct is @set("Id", 1) instead of @set("Id":1).

Comment: Can you give me the JavaScript equivalent, I'm not using coffee script.

Comment: Added on the solution.